# Playing Audio from Cache Directory

Tags: android

When playing audio from sdcard, `MediaPlayer` plays the file. But when playing from `getCacheDir()` it is an error. Is my conclusion right that `MediaPlayer` can't play files from `getCacheDir()` ?

Here's a code snippet:

```
private void startPlaying(String asAudioFileName) {
    File fFile = new File(VocaPreview.this.getCacheDir() + "/" + asAudioFileName.toLowerCase() + ".mp3");

    if(!fFile.isFile()) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "File not found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        try {
            FileInputStream fisAudio = new FileInputStream(fFile);
            //fmpAudio.setDataSource(VocaPreview.this.getCacheDir() + "/" +  asAudioFileName.toLowerCase() + ".mp3");
            //fmpAudio.setDataSource("/sdcard/2.mp3");

            fmpAudio.setDataSource(fisAudio.getFD());
            fmpAudio.prepare();
            fmpAudio.start();
        } catch(IOException ioe) {
            Log.e("START PLAYING", ioe.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

UPDATE:
I just read from this [Blog](http://www.weston-fl.com/blog/?p) and solved my problem, inorder for me to play audio inside a cache, I added this line and that's it. Hope this helps anyone in the future. [Here is the method](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#setReadable%28boolean,%20boolean%29).

```
File file = new File(filepath)
file.setReadable(true, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a function that also works on API levels < 9:

`Runtime.getRuntime().exec("chmod 644 "+ outputFile.getAbsolutePath());`